# VueJS. Se puede agregar la propiedad v-on a una tag transition-group?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Vuejs 2.5, en el cual tengo una tabla dinamica con una animacion que se la proveo de la etiqueta predeterminada  y en ella le digo que va a funcionar como un tbody de manera que el efecto salga con cada tr que aparezca.

```
<transition-group 
    class="tbody" 
    name="list-complete" 
    tag='tbody'>
                    <tr v-for='x in xlist'
                        :class="{
                            'tr':true, 
                            'font18':true,
                            'is-selected':(x.id == selected.id), 
                            'list-complete-item':true,
                        }" 
                        @click="focus(x)" 
                        :key='x.id'>
                        <td class="td is-unselectable font12 tmiddle" width="5%">
                            {{ x.id }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="td is-unselectable is-uppercase" width="30%">
                            {{ x.title }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="td font14 is-unselectable is-italic tmiddle is-uppercase" width="20%">
                            {{ x.mood_title }}
                            <!--span class="is-pulled-right">//</span-->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td font14 is-unselectable is-italic tmiddle is-uppercase" width="20%">
                            {{ x.genere_title }}
                            <!--span class="is-pulled-right">//</span-->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td font14 is-unselectable is-italic tmiddle" width="10%">
                            {{ x.bpm }}BPM
                            <!--span class="is-pulled-right">//</span-->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td font14 is-unselectable is-italic tmiddle" width="15%">
                            {{ x.duration }}MIN
                            <!--span class="is-pulled-right">//</span-->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td font14 is-unselectable is-italic tmiddle" width="10%">
                            {{ x.price }}$USD
                        </td>                                   
                    </tr>
</transition-group>
```

Al momento de hacer la paginacion me toco utilizar la tabla con scroll de manera que cuando el usuario llegara al final de la tabla se le agregen mas datos.
El problema esta que cuando le agrego una propiedad v-on:scroll o @scroll, no funciona en el transition-group. Aunque si se lo agrego una etiqueta tbody normal si funciona, pero pierdo la transicion.

```
   <transition-group 
                class="tbody" 
                name="list-complete" 
                tag='tbody'
                @scroll="handleScroll">

<tbody @scroll="handleScroll" transition="list-complete">
```

aqui el metodo:

```
    handleScroll: function(e) {
        var currentScrollPosition = e.srcElement.scrollTop;
        if (currentScrollPosition > this.scrollPosition) {
            console.log("Scrolling down");
        }
        this.scrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;
    },
```

Habra alguna manera de que puedan funcionar los dos?

Comment: No se como solucionar tu problema. Pero ninguna de las tablas por defecto que tiene VUE te sirvio? hay montones ya programadas

Comment: Lo intente pero por las especificaciones del sistema que dieron no me funcionaba ninguna, tuve que implementar la tabla yo mismo, me pareció mas sencillo y Bueh... Si tengo que quitarle las transiciones lo haré igual gracias por responder.

Comment: Intentaste tomando este camino: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats Intenta usando `is` en el tbody para hacer referencia al componente y intenta enlazar el evento

Comment: Todo se puede a nivel javascript ;)